# True statements about natural numbers that are undecidable in Peano Arithmetic assuming consistency of PA only

Tags: logic, set-theory, peano-axioms

I am looking for statements $P$ of Peano Arithmetic ($\textsf{PA}$) that have the following properties:

- They are as concrete and simple as possible.
- It is provable by finitistic means that neither $P$ nor $\neg P$ can be proved within $\textsf{PA}$, in the sense that a proof of either of both can be turned into an inconsistency of $\textsf{PA}$.
- Ideally, I'd like $P$ to be true in the standard natural numbers of $\textsf{ZFC}$, say.

The third point implies the unprovability of $\neg P$ in $\textsf{PA}$ assuming the consistency of $\textsf{ZFC}$ (i.e., there is a way of turning a proof of $\neg P$ in $\textsf{PA}$ into an inconsistency of $\textsf{ZFC}$). However, this is not as strong as the finitistic argument I am looking for in the second point.

*To clarify:* The whole point of the question is that I don't want to rely on a strong ambient set theory like $\textsf{ZFC}$ for the proof of undecidability of $P$, but rather have an algorithm turning a hypothetical proof of $P$ or $\neg P$ into an inconsistency of $\textsf{PA}$.

The example $P = \text{Con}\ \textsf{PA}$ that DanulG mentioned actually does meet half of the requirements, since as far as I understand Goedel's argument is, in principle, of the desired algorithmic nature. With the Rosser trick, one can indeed get a statement $P$ such that also a proof of $\neg P$ can be turned into an inconsistency of $\text{Con}\ \textsf{PA}$. However, I'd be a bit happier with non metamathematical statements. Goodstein's Theorem or Kirby-Paris' "Hydra" would be fine, for example.

*2nd edit:* The Paris-Harrington Theorem (http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/ph.pdf) meets at least half of the requirements, as Paris and Harrington show that the combinatorial principle $Q$ they consider implies $\text{Con}\ \textsf{PA}$ within $\textsf{PA}$, i.e. they prove $\textsf{PA} \vdash (Q\Rightarrow \text{Con}\ \textsf{PA})$. What about $\neg Q$? Surely we cannot have $\textsf{PA}\vdash (\neg Q\Rightarrow\text{Con}\ \textsf{PA})$ as well, but is there still some finitistic means to deduce from a proof of $\neg Q$ an inconsistency of $\textsf{PA}$, and not only of $\textsf{ZFC}$ or whatever stronger set theory one has to use to prove $Q$? Any ideas here?

Thank you!

Comment: Con PA satisfies every one of these.

Comment: The usual example here is Goodstein's theorem, the Paris-Harrington theorem, and related matters.  If that isn't what you are looking for,  please amend your question to explain why it isn't.

Comment: Maybe see [Kanamori-McAloon.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanamori%E2%80%93McAloon_theorem)

Comment: @MJD: As far as I understand, applying model theoretic arguments here only proves undecidability of $P$ in the sense that a proof of either $P$ or $\neg P$ in PA would yield an inconsistency of the ambient set theory. However, I would like to build on consistency of PA alone, i.e. algorithmically turn a proof of $P$ or $\neg P$ into an inconsistency of PA.

Comment: @Hanno All these examples can be argued proof theoretically within $\mathsf{PA}$, no need for stepping outside or for stronger set theoretic assumptions. The book **Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic** discusses this in detail. One can also argue within $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, a theory that is conservative over $\mathsf{PA}$ for arithmetic statements, but allows for some basic model theoretic arguments.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you! I have to admit, I cannot imagine at the moment how one might formalize the arguments concerning infinite models within PA and with reference to PA only, but I will look at the reference you gave, and this will probably make things clearer. If you want, feel free to add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Also, if you don't mind, I'd be happy about a rough sketch of, for example, the proof that the termination of Kirby-Paris' Hydra cannot be disproved from PA unless PA (and not only a set theory admitting the countable ordinals) is inconsistent, which might give a first impression of how things can be formalized in PA.